# Linearly independent subset of polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $S$ be a set of non-zero polynomials over a field $F$. If no two elements of $S$ have the same degree, show that $S$ is an independent subset of $F[x]$.

I tried to prove the statement by induction on the number of elements of any finite subset of $S$.  Please let me know if my proof is correct or not.
Besides, is there other method to prove the statement?

Thanks!

Let n be the number of elements in a finite subset of S.

Base case $n = 1$

$\alpha f = 0 \implies \alpha = 0$ because $f \ne 0$.

Assume the statement is true for $n=k$.

When $n = k+1$,
suppose $$\sigma= \alpha_1 f_1+....+\alpha_k f_k+ \alpha_{k+1} f_{k+1}=0$$
WLOG, we may assume that $f_{k+1}$ has the highest degree among all $f_i${i=1,2,...,k+1}. Let $m= \deg f_{k+1}$

Denote the leading coefficient of $f_{k+1}$ by $\lambda$.

The coefficient of $x^{m}$ will be zero for all other $f_i$.

Note that the coefficient of $x^{m}$ in $\sigma$ will then be $$\alpha_{k+1}\lambda=0$$
By the definition of leading coefficient, $$\lambda  \ne 0$$. So $$\alpha_{k+1}=0$$
This implies $$\alpha_1 f_1+....+\alpha_k f_k=0$$
By induction assumption, $$\alpha_1 = \alpha_2=...=\alpha_{k}=0$$
Hence, $f_1,f_2,....,f_{k+1}$ are linearly independent.
By the principle of M.I., the statement is true for all natural numbers n.

Best regards,
Michael

Comment: Correct.${}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 1):

Here is my take.

Order the polynomials in $S$ by decreasing degree.

Write their coefficients in a matrix, from higher degree to lower degree.

The resulting matrix is in [row echelon form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_echelon_form) and has no zero rows, and so has full rank.

Therefore, $S$ is linearly independent.

For example, if $S = \{1+x^3+x^4, x^2+x^6, x+x^7 \}$, then the matrix is
$$
\pmatrix{
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
}
$$

Comment: Sorry, I can't follow your procedure. Take for example, if $f_1=1+x^3+x^4$, $f_2=x^2+x^6$ and $f_3=x+x^7$, then what will be the matrix?

Comment: ,Oh! I see, you mean row echelon form.Very nice method. When I used induction to prove the statement I felt that I din't understand the reason  why these elements are linearly independent. Now I totally understand the reasoning behind. Thanks a lot!

Comment: that's probably the best way to approach the problem (+1)!